# It is in regards to an email from google about migrating discontinued documents list API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I received this email and due to my lack of experience in google drive, I am unsure of how to go about troubleshooting this.

Google
IMPORTANT: Steps to migrate from discontinued Documents List API
Hello administrators,

We recently posted a reminder that Documents List API will be discontinued on April 20, 2015. This change means that service calls for this API will no longer be supported, and any Google Apps features that are implemented using this API will no longer function.

Our records indicate that you may have an application that uses Documents List API, and we  recommend that you migrate to Drive API, which has comparable functionality, as soon as possible.

Here's what you need to do:

Determine if you have an application that makes requests to these types of URLs:

(took out urls since this format did not allow me to send more than two)

Migrate the applications to Drive API.

If you have questions about migration, please contact Google Apps for Work Support.

Sincerely,
The Google Apps for Work Team

How do I determine, which, if any, docs are going to cease to function post 4/20? Is there a way to organize my current list of docs (I have many) to see how many I need to pay attention to? In terms of migrating, is there a migrating tool available online?

From what I have read, I feel like this doesn't even pertain to my current drive. My understanding is that this is for developers not casual users such as myself. Am I wrong in that assumption?

Thank you for all your help in this matter. If I am not explaining everything to the level you need, please let me know. I am just confused by the email and want to make sure I stay ahead of this.

Best,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

The key part of the email is **Our records indicate that you may have an application that uses Documents List API**

If you have such an app (you should know since by implication, you wrote it), then you have a lot of work to do over the next two weeks. If you don't, then relax. Your documents are **not** affected by this announcement, only the app that Google thinks you once wrote.

It's possible it's referring to an app you have installed, in which case there is nothing you can do other than hope the developer has a new version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook and Google Drive Windows seem to be the 2 applications that are requesting access to these depecrated scopes ... Come on Google, spread the word internally !